# Problema con contraseña de usuario sa en sql server. La contraseña se resetea o expira sola

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Hola tengo sql server 2019 pero con el 2017 tambíen me pasa y tengo el management studio 18.4. Se que el usuario sa no debería usarse pero bueno tengo que usarlo y necesito que la contraseña sea sa. Es decir al usuario sa necesito ponerle la contraseña sa. Para esto en varias ocasiones desmarco la casilla Enforce password policy y Enforce password expiration, también lo he hecho con una sentencia similar a esta: `ALTER LOGIN [user] WITH PASSWORD = '****' ;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero por alguna razón la contraseña de este usuario como que se resetea o se expira cada cierta cantidad de minutos, no se que es lo que pasa y tengo que estarla cambiando a cada rato. Como hago para establecerle la contraseña de forma permanente???

Comment: Las contraseñas no se cambian solas. Tampoco expiran a los pocos minutos. Debes de revisar en tu empresa para  ver quien puede estar cambiando la contraseña.

Comment: No es una empresa, es un servidor personal. Nadie tiene acceso. Yo me doy cuenta que la contraseña se cambia porque hay un servicio de windows conectado a a la bd y  el servicio empieza a tirar errores de loggin luego de un rato. Sospecho que ese servicio provoca alguna situación de seguridad o algo así y entonces eso hace que el usuario como que se resetee o microsoft bloquee el acceso no se algo extraño, pero le puedo asegurar que nadie cambia la contraseña

Comment: Te va a ir mejor si nos muestras los errores que ves cuando dices que deja de funcionar. De paso, revisa la tabla [`syslogins`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslogins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) o [`database_principals`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) para ver la fecha y hora de última actualización sobre la cuenta sa.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me esta pasando lo mismo y eso me sucede desde que configure una IP Publica y agregue en el router la IP del servidor y luego desde el SQL Server Configuration manager configure para que tuviera acceso desde fuera.

Utilizo el usuario sa para una aplicación que cree y cada cierto tiempo se me reinicia sola la contraseña del usuario sa y tengo que estar ingresando la contraseña para que deje de dar el error de acceso al sistema.

Comment: Esto **no es una respuesta**, puedes generar tu propia pregunta y así obtener una respuesta mas personalizada. Evita dejar comentarios en la zonas de respuesta, date una vuelta en (Cómo dar una buena respuesta)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer].

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/354663)

Answer (score 0):

No ve visto que haya particularidades de MSSQL 2019 sobre ésto, así que puedo ofrecerte un par de opciones:

1. Revisa el modo de autenticación. Si no lo tienes mixto, esto puede pasar. Puede incluso que realmente no estés cambiando nunca la contraseña (no queda registro en la tabla [`sql_logins`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-logins-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Déjalo en mixto y confirma justo después del cambio que sí puedes conectarte con las nuevas credenciales.

Revisa siempre [server_principals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-server-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

2. Créate un login nuevo con rol sysadmin.

```
> CREATE LOGIN [login_name] WITH PASSWORD='[password]';
> GO
> SP_ADDSRVROLEMEMBER [login_name],'SYSADMIN'; 
> GO
```

Como para que no sufras con políticas de grupos que no estés controlando.